# POO: impresión de valores, sobre los parametros e invocación de metodos

Tags: java, poo, get, set

Estoy repasando para mi exámen de POO en Java y tengo este proyecto, se supone que tengo que hacer los aguinaldos de cada empleado dentro de una tienda e imprimir todos los datos de cada uno de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los aguinaldos se calculan de esta forma dependiendo del puesto del trabajador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que hacer dos clases las cuales son Trabajador.java y Principal.java, siendo Principal la clase main, para empezar dentro de la clase Trabajador hay tres atributos los cuales declaro un poco más abajo, hice un método constructor por omisión y otro constructor con parámetros en esta misma clase y al final de todo tengo un método para calcular el aguinaldo del empleado respecto a la tabla que ya adjunté.

Ahora bien, no hay lectura de datos por lo que los valores de nombre, puesto y sueldo se los tengo que asignar yo con los métodos Set se supone, lo cual es lo que hago en la clase Principal, aunque según las instrucciones el aguinaldo no se considera un atributo, adjunto código con la clase Trabajador:

```
public class Trabajador {

    //Declaro atributos
    private String nombre;
    private String puesto;
    private float sueldo;
    //Método constructor por omisión
    public Trabajador(){
        
    }
    //Constructor con parámetros
    public Trabajador(String nombre, String puesto, float sueldo){
        
    }
    //Métodos Get y Set de cada atributo
    public void setNombre (String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public String getNombre (){
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setPuesto (String puesto){
        this.puesto = puesto;
    }
    
    public String getPuesto (){
        return puesto;
    }
    
    public void setSueldo (float sueldo){
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }
    
    public float getSueldo (){
        return sueldo;
    }
    //Método para calcular el aguinaldo dependiendo del puesto del empleado
    public float Aguinaldo (){
        if ("Coordinador".equalsIgnoreCase(puesto)){
            double aguinaldo = sueldo*0.87;
            return (float) aguinaldo;
        }
        else if ("Supervisor".equalsIgnoreCase(puesto)){
            double aguinaldo = sueldo*0.91;
            return (float) aguinaldo;
        }
        else{
            double aguinaldo = sueldo*0.98;
            return (float) aguinaldo;
        }        
    }
    //Método para calcular el total (sueldo+aguinaldo) del empleado
    public float Total(float aguinaldo){
        float total = sueldo + aguinaldo;
        return total;
    }
    //Método para imprimir la tabla con los 
    public void MostrarTabla(Trabajador trabajador1, Trabajador trabajador2, Trabajador trabajador3, float aguinaldo){
        System.out.println("Nombre del empleado     Puesto  Sueldo  Aguinaldo       Total");
        System.out.println("-------------------     ------  ------  ---------       -----");
        System.out.println(trabajador1.getNombre()+trabajador1.getPuesto()+trabajador1.getSueldo()+trabajador1.Aguinaldo()+trabajador1.Total(aguinaldo));
        System.out.println(trabajador2.getNombre()+trabajador2.getPuesto()+trabajador2.getSueldo()+trabajador2.Aguinaldo()+trabajador2.Total(aguinaldo));
        System.out.println(trabajador3.getNombre()+trabajador3.getPuesto()+trabajador3.getSueldo()+trabajador3.Aguinaldo()+trabajador3.Total(aguinaldo));
        System.out.println("------------------      -----   ------  ---------       -----");
        System.out.println("Totales                         ");
    }
}
```

No entiendo muy bien porque en la vista previa no detecta el codigo que está mas arriba en el que pongo el public Class y otras cosas pero espero y se aprecie, bueno, ahora sobre la clase principal tengo que crear tres objetos de tipo trabajador, establecer los valores de acuerdo a la tabla con donde especifica que debo de poner en cada atributo (nombre, puesto, sueldo) y al final debo solicitar al objeto tipo Aguinaldo la impresión de la tabla.

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Trabajador trabajador1 = new Trabajador();
        Trabajador trabajador2 = new Trabajador();
        Trabajador trabajador3 = new Trabajador();
        
        trabajador1.setNombre("Alex Martinez");
        trabajador1.setPuesto("Coordinador");
        trabajador1.setSueldo((float) 13430.41);
        
        trabajador2.setNombre("Brayan Zavala");
        trabajador2.setPuesto("Supervisor");
        trabajador2.setSueldo((float) 10853.82);
        
        trabajador3.setNombre("Alvaro Romero");
        trabajador3.setPuesto("Vendedor");
        trabajador3.setSueldo((float) 7951.91);
        
        trabajador1.MostrarTabla();
    }
    
}
```

Tengo varios problemas con este ejercicio:

1. Las instrucciones no especifican si debo de crear un metodo para imprimir lo que se pide, tampoco para calcular el total, pero yo supongo que sí y por eso tengo el metodo MostrarTabla() pero no se como imprimir con formato así que lo hago como puedo pero aun asi se puede ver como deje el metodo sin completar porque no se me ocurrió como imprimir bien

2.En la clase principal, se puede ver que creo los objetos y les establezco los valores correspondientes pero al momento de invocar al metodo MostrarTabla no se cuales son los argumentos que deberia de enviar, en fin que lo que tiene que ver con la impresion es lo que se me está complicando

3.Tampoco sé en que momento del código debo de calcular el total de cada empleado y también los totales de la parte de abajo de la tabla por eso es que no lo escribí ya que aunque hice el método Total() no estoy seguro si es la forma correcta de hacerlo

Espero me ayuden a resolver esos 3 puntos y si ven alguna corrección que pueda hacer a mi codigo, se agradeceria que me la hagan saber, muchas gracias.

Comment: Para que el código quede bien indentado, tienes que seleccionar todo el bloque de código y luego hacer click sobre el símbolo **`{ }`**. La cuestión es que todas las líneas deben tener al menos 4 espacios en blanco, si el inicio de la clase u otros no tienen esos 4 espacios se interpretan como texto normal, no como código.

Comment: Por otra parte tu pregunta no es del todo clara: 1. *Las instrucciones no especifican si...* **¿qué instrucciones?** 2. `mostrarTabla()` no debe estar jamás en la clase `Trabajador`, es absurdo tenerlo ahí, podría estar en la clase principal (como un array de objetos del tipo `Trabajador` o en una clase `Empresa`, o una clase `Supervisor` o algo así, que sí poseería un grupo de trabajadores. Algo que ayuda mucho a entender la POO es **pensar las cosas como son en la realidad**. ¿Acaso un `Trabajador` contiene al mismo tiempo un grupo de trabajadores?

Comment: 3. *En qué momento calcular el total de cada empleado*. Esa duda es por el problema expuesto en (2). En `Trabajador` ya tienes un método que calcula el total de **ese** trabajador. Pero el **total de todos los trabajadores** debe calcularse en aquella clase que tendría la lista de trabajadores, que debería ser, como ya se dijo, la clase Principal o en otra que sí puede contener grupos de trabajadores. Pero como intentas manejar grupos de trabajadores desde la misma clase `Trabajador` todo se nubla en tu diseño. El principal problema es esa comprensión equivocada de la POO.

Answer (score 0):

Veo varios problemas en tu código. Ya te indiqué algunas cosas en mis comentarios en la pregunta.

Un método muy sencillo para enteder la POO es pensarla desde la realidad misma. Las clases de tipo **entidad**, como es `Trabajador` en el caso que expones, deben ser pensadas como moldes para construir objetos de ese tipo. Si en esa clase tú colocas otros métodos **circunstanciales**, como es el actual método `MostrarTabla()`, estás capando la clase, o sobrecargándola. Es decir, todas las instancias de `Trabajador` tendrán acceso a ese método, sin necesidad de ello.

¿Acaso **todo** `Trabajador` debe tener manejo de sí mismo y de otros dos trabajadores más como expresas en tu actual método `MostrarTabla()` metido en la clase `Trabajador`? La respuesta es un rotundo **NO**.

Pensando desde la realidad, quien sí podría manejar una lista de trabajador sería tu clase `Principal`, o una eventual clase `Empresa` o una eventual clase `Supervisor` (que supervisa a varios trabajadores), etc... No sé si me explico: **la realidad, sí, la realidad ayuda a entender la POO**, es muy simple y esa es una de sus ventajas principales precisamente.

Dicho eso, hay más cosas aparte de lo que te dije ya en mis comentarios en la pregunta.

- No tiene sentido crear un constructor con parámetros si luego no asignas los valores que pasas en ese constructor. Mejoraré eso, porque en contextos donde necesites crear instancias para trabajar con grupos, te va a ahorrar mucho en verbosidad, pudiendo llenar una lista de objetos `Trabajador` sin tener que crear las instancias y luego llenarlas con cada método *set*. Es diferente si necesitaras luego trabajar con cada instancia en particular... No parece ser el caso en tu ejercicio.
- `float` no es un tipo adecuado para manejar valores monetarios. Si debes usar primitivos, por mandato del ejercicio, usa `double` y, si puedes, usa `Decimal` que sería lo mejor. Esto es debido a que `float` tiene problemas serios de precisión para valores monetarios.
- Respeta la convención de nombre, no la estás aplicando de modo adecuado en algunos métodos.
- El `aguinaldo` lo voy a dejar en la clase trabajador, pero, siguiendo con lo que te decía sobre pensar las cosas basándote en la realidad, la lógica para calcular el aguinaldo **tampoco debería ir en la clase `Trabajador`**. La dejo ahí por falta de contexto (no sé que otras clases debe tener tu programa). Pero lo lógico es que esa lógica vaya en otra clase, digamos una clase `Empresa` donde se decide qué aguinaldo se aplica según el puesto de trabajo. Esa clase podría tener un `HashMap` que asocie puesto con valor de aguinaldo a aplicar. Es más, `Aguinaldo` puede ser una clase en sí misma. Pensemos en algo mínimamente complejo, como que los aguinaldos se apliquen según el mes, o según la antiguedad del empleado o según el país ... o cosas así.

Te propongo esto, en el código he comentado más cosas. Son bastantes las mejoras que debes aplicar y puede que se me hayan escapado detalles, pero con esto tendrás un programa más o menos decente desde el punto de vista de la POO.

En el ejemplo, he puesto a la clase principal el nombre de `Rextester` porque así lo exige el sitio para que el código pueda funcionar.

#### Clase principal

```
class Rextester    
{
    private static ArrayList<Trabajador> allWorkers;
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        allWorkers = new ArrayList<>();
        Trabajador trabajador1 = new Trabajador();
        allWorkers.add(new Trabajador("Alex Martínez","Coordinador",13430.41));
        allWorkers.add(new Trabajador("Brayan Zavala","Supervisor",10853.82));
        allWorkers.add(new Trabajador("Alvaro Romero","Vendedor",7951.91));
        
        showData();
        
        showTotalGeneral();       
        
    }
    
        /*
            Este sería el equivalente de tu método MostrarTabla()
            el cual no debería ir NUNCA en una clase de tipo entidad
            como es Trabajador, porque este es un método circunstancial
            es decir, propio de un contexto concreto o de otra entidad
            como sería Empresa, o Supervisor, o algo así 
        */
        private static void showData() {
            String format = "%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%s%n";
            System.out.printf(format,"Empleado","Puesto","Sueldo","Aguinaldo","Total");
            System.out.printf(format,"-------------------","------","------","------","------");
            allWorkers.forEach((w) -> System.out.println(w.toString()));
            System.out.printf(format,"-------------------","------","------","------","------");
            
        } 

        private static void showTotalGeneral() {
            double theTotal = allWorkers.stream().mapToDouble(f -> f.getTotal()).sum();
            System.out.printf("TOTAL GENERAL:\t%,-20.2f",theTotal);
        }     
}
```

---

#### Clase `Trabajador`

```
class Trabajador {

    //Declaro atributos
    private String nombre;
    private String puesto;
    private double sueldo;
    //Método constructor por omisión
    public Trabajador(){
        
    }
    //Constructor con parámetros
    public Trabajador(String nombre, String puesto, double sueldo){
        //Asignamos cada atributo 
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.puesto=puesto;
        this.sueldo=sueldo;
        
    }
    //Métodos Get y Set de cada atributo
    public void setNombre (String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public String getNombre (){
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setPuesto (String puesto){
        this.puesto = puesto;
    }
    
    public String getPuesto (){
        return puesto;
    }
    
    public void setSueldo (double sueldo){
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }
    
    public double getSueldo (){
        return sueldo;
    }
    /*
        Método para calcular el aguinaldo dependiendo del puesto del empleado
        Lo dejamos aquí por falta de contexto
        Pero este método debería ir en una clase Empresa
        o bien ser una clase en sí misma.
        Cabe decir que este método es algo DEFICIENTE 
        pues el else al final asume que sin importar el tipo
        se aplicará el aguinaldo definido para Vendedor ...
        Si yo paso una cadena vacía para el puesto, asumirá
        que es un Vendedor ... faltan controles al respecto       
    */
    public double getAguinaldo (){
        if ("Coordinador".equalsIgnoreCase(puesto)){
            double aguinaldo = sueldo*0.87;
            return aguinaldo;
        }
        else if ("Supervisor".equalsIgnoreCase(puesto)){
            double aguinaldo = sueldo*0.91;
            return aguinaldo;
        }
        else{
            double aguinaldo = sueldo*0.98;
            return aguinaldo;
        }        
    }
    //Método para calcular el total (sueldo+aguinaldo) del empleado
    public double getTotal(){
        double total = sueldo + getAguinaldo();
        return total;
    }
    
    //Método para mostrar la info de cada Trabajador
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%-20s%-20s%,-20.2f%,-20.2f%,.2f%n",getNombre(),getPuesto(),getSueldo(),getAguinaldo(),getTotal());
    }
}
```

#### Ejemplo

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo y hacer pruebas sobre él: <kbd>[VER FIDDLE](https://rextester.com/ZPQN84648)</kbd>.